API Endpoint - Calling path/file.php works but doesn't by endpoint
I made a simple API with PHP
When I call it (Postman or script) with https://www.example.org/api/index_api.php it works. I get the return value.
When I call it (Postman or script) with https://www.example.org/api/ it doesn't.
Object sent
{
  "id": "alberto",
  "name": "test name naaame ",
  "email": "jane@doe.com"
}

index_api.php (simplified: here, I don't use $method):
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$input = mb_convert_encoding($input, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
//
echo json_encode(['3' => 'De vuelta de API : ' . $input['name'] ]);


I'd be really grateful to receive some help.
I tried a lot of URL rewrite rules in .htaccess, but no success.
When it's for myself, I use complete path but it's not an API.
And I need to call it

for clients
from inside a WP plugin

Thanks by advance

Please provide your webserver configuration. It seems you need to set up the index file correctly in the webserver configuration, but I'm not sure until I see it.

@Mikhail Chuloshnikov : Thanks, you are totally right: I've just installed my scripts on a MAMP, and it works.
The server on which i made previous tests is a VPS with Plesk. I'll dig into this direction
Thanks a lot

What happens when index_api.php is renamed to index.php? It works with ../api/index_api.php because you specify which file should be used, I think that when using ../api/ it tries to look for an index.php file, which obviously does not exist.

@geertjanknapen : Thanks for suggesting
I've tried using index.php. Whatever the name of the php file I specify in the htacess, same result.
After reinstalling my server without Plesk, all is working perfectly.
The problem comes from Plesk or my lack of knowledge of how it works.
Thanks to the people who helped me, I think my request was badly formulated. The title should have been : Htaccess problem of a specific directory in conflict with general redirection rules on a Plesk (Obsidian) / Ubuntu (22.04)

@LenaLfPC You could try setting a default index type in Plesk Obsidian. I don't have experience with Plesk, but that could do the trick.

"I think my request was badly formulated. The title should have been : Htaccess problem of a specific directory in conflict with general redirection rules on a Plesk (Obsidian) / Ubuntu (22.04)" - then the info provided should match that as well. So far, we have not seen anything of your .htaccess, and neither do we have the info, what gets redirected via any "general redirection rules."

Thank you all.
I'm new to server management...
I manage to do everything I want (slowly), with an SSH console, but I have really serious lacks when it comes to Plesk.
I reinstalled the VPS without Plesk
Everything works perfectly.
I think we can close this discussion, and I don't see any harm in it being closed or deleted. I didn't word my question well initially and I don't think anyone will learn anything from reading this discussion.
